# mongoose js won't print out query value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create using mongoose js a collection of kitten with this document in it {name: "mike"}.

After creating this document I want to print it's value.

I wrote this code below.

2 problems:

1. this code doesn't end (meaning when I wrote `node file.js` the cmd line stays open (stucked) and no return value is return (infinite loop like in a server).
2. the code doesn't print the value of "mike". just create this doucument...

what am I doing wrong?

thanks

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var url = 'mongodb://Yotam:Yotam@ds023475.mlab.com:23475/small-talkz';
mongoose.connect(url);

var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

var Kitten = mongoose.model('kitten', kittySchema);

 Kitten.create({ name: "mike" }, function (err, small) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

});  

 Kitten.findOne( { } ), function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs.name);
};  
return 1;
```

Comment: the silent -1 stackoverflow ghost strikes again.. sigh... can somebody please help? I tried to find help in the mongoose documentation and fell short.

Answer (score 1):

```
newKitten = { name: "mike" };

Kitten.create(newKitten, function (err, kitty) {
    if {
      (err) return handleError(err);
    } else {
      console.log(kitty); //OR console.log(kitty.name);
    }
}); 

Kitten.findOne({name: "mike"}).exec(function(e, kitten) {
    if (e) {
        console.log(e)
    } else {
        console.log(kitten.name)
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to print this value by query (aka find(....)). not by create(...)

Answer (score 0):

the problem was {for anyone whose intersted (and thanks for herkou)} that I did not use the exec command..

This works:

```
 Kitten.findOne( { name: "mike"} ).exec( function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs.name);
    return;
});
```

update:

also had a probelm with race conditions... the create of the documnet not finished when the query was called. that is why I got undeinfed.

use this new code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var url = 'mongodb://Yotam:Yotam@ds023475.mlab.com:23475/small-talkz';
mongoose.connect(url);

var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    color:String
});

var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

var newKitten = { name: "mike", color:"white" };

Kitten.create(newKitten, function (err, kitty) {
    if (err) {
        return handleError(err);
    } else {
        call_query();
    }
}); 


var call_query= function(){
    var query= Kitten.findOne( { name: "mike"} );
    query.exec( function(err, docs){
        console.log(docs.color);
        return;
    });  
}

return 1;
```

now I just need to understand why this script doesn't end.